# Gnuplot: errorbars in polar mode

Tags: gnuplot

Is it possible to use error bars with GnuPlot in polar mode? I only managed to draw yerrorbars but xerrorbars are not working. What can I do about it?

I have data in file in form:

```
x <tab> y <tab> x_error <tab> y_error
```

Drawing like that

```
plot 'data.txt' using 1:2:4 t "title" with yerrorbars
```

works.

But I want to be able to do something like that

```
plot 'data.txt' using 1:2:3:4 t "title" with xyerrorbars
```

like I used to do with non polar graphs.

Comment: You need to give more detail here regarding the format of your data and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Tom Fenech Updated my question a bit.